# How can I combine two collections in MongoDB depending on different IDs?

Tags: mongodb, collections, lookup

I want to join two collections of MongoDB. I want to join them if the _id and the creatorId matches. This is what I have done.

```
User.aggregate([
        {
           $lookup:
              {
                from: "traveladds",
                let: { personalId: "$_id"},
                pipeline: [
                   { $match:
                      { $expr:
                            [
                              { $eq: [ "$creatorId",  "$$personalId" ] },
                            ]
                         }
                   }
                ],
                as: "stockdata"
              }
         },
     ]).exec((err, result) => {
        if(err){
            res.send(err)
        }
        if(result){
            res.send({
                error: false, 
                data: result, 
            })
        }
    })
```

But when I do like this, all of the documents in *traveladds*-collection is stored in stockdata for all the users.

User collection:

```
"_id": "609bc1b9bbc4ff184194c20f",
  "homeCountry": "",
  "birthdate": "",
  "email": "",
  "password": "",
  "firstName": "",
  "lastName": "",
  "__v": 0,
  "about": "",
  "gender": "",
```

Traveladds collection:

```
"{
  "_id": "609bc1fdbbc4ff184194c210",
  "title": "",
  "destination": "",
  "description": "",
  "minbudget": ,
  "maxbudget": ,
  "startdate": "",
  "enddate": "",
  "creatorId": "609bc1b9bbc4ff184194c20f",
  "creatorName": "",
  "createdAt": "",
  "updatedAt": "",
  "__v": 0
},
```

And this is the result:

```
data": [
{
  "_id": "609bc1b9bbc4ff184194c20f",
  "homeCountry": "",
  "birthdate": "",
  "email": "",
  "password": "",
  "firstName": "",
  "lastName": "",
  "__v": 0,
  "about": "",
  "gender": "",
  "stockdata": [
    {
      "_id": "609bc1fdbbc4ff184194c210",
      "title": "",
      "destination": "",
      "description": "",
      "minbudget": ,
      "maxbudget": ,
      "startdate": "",
      "enddate": "",
      "creatorId": "609bc1b9bbc4ff184194c20f",
      "creatorName": "",
      "createdAt": "",
      "updatedAt": "",
      "__v": 0
    },
     {
      "_id": "609eb5f401c77217984e4a78",
      "title": "",
      "destination": "",
      "description": "",
      "minbudget": ,
      "maxbudget": ,
      "startdate": "",
      "enddate": "",
      "creatorId": "609e9bb378336c21581cd132",
      "creatorName": "",
      "createdAt": "",
      "updatedAt": "",
      "__v": 0
    },
     {
      "_id": "60a216cfd43c8e1e375cf0a8",
      "title": "",
      "destination": "",
      "description": "",
      "minbudget": ,
      "maxbudget": ,
      "startdate": "",
      "enddate": "",
      "creatorId": "609e39572c60480de0fd6ef1",
      "creatorName": "",
      "createdAt": "",
      "updatedAt": "",
      "__v": 0
    },
  ]
},
```

As you can see, even though there are creatorId != _id it shows in the stockdata. And all these three appears in all users.

Can someone provide me with any idéas what to do?
Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

**UPDATE:**
This in combination with the answer below worked!

personalId: {$toString: "$_id"}

Comment: can you how us both collections

Comment: Hello, I added some pictures, is this what you ment? :)

Comment: Better please dont post any images, you can edit the question and update you collection as snippets it!

Comment: Hope this is better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written correct query. But there are some unnecessary brackets

```
 db.User.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "traveladds",
          let: {
            personalId: "$_id"
          },
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match: {
                $expr: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$creatorId",
                    "$$personalId"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          as: "stockdata"
        }
      },
      
    ])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1_DDZ2-uJD4)**

Comment: hmm, if I try this all of my stockdata becomes empty [], for all users.

Comment: you are joining `user._id` with `traveladds.creatorId`. So it will give you only the joining documents.... What else you need

Comment: Thank you for your help! Another problem was that the $_id had to be converted to:  personalId: {$toString: "$_id"}!! Many thanks for your time